# Iphone : How to detect Facebook login was disabled by user in ios6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, ios6

Hello How do I check if the user turn off the Facebook login setting of our application in IOS6. or if turned off, can user switch to a old way to logon the application.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]){
>        //user has setup Facebook settings
>   }
>   else{
>       //not set Facebook settings,
>  }
> ```

You can use Facebook SDK if user havent setup the facebook login, I have tried this once but it throws some error in iOS6 case.